# How to distinguish real programming bugs from issues with startup parameters

Tags: linux, centos, centos5, core-file

I'm working on a CentOS system, as requested by one of my customers.

Recently a bug has been reported, mentioning that in a particular case, a core-file was generated.

After a huge amount of work, I realised that the problem was not due to my program behaving badly, but to internal configuration: my program (being a Java program) was started up without `-Xss` option. The machine automatically set a maximum stack size which was too small and as a result the program crashed.
Now I've solved that bug simply by adding `-Xss2m` to the Java startup parameters of my program.

Now I'm wondering: imagine that a program goes bad on such a CentOS system. Is it possible to configure the system in such a way that I can easily know whether the problem is caused by a malfunctioning program or by a configuration/startup parameters issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming a distinction where non-exists.

When you supply a program, you supply it with all relevant arguments and environment. If your program crashes, then you have a bug. It might be a packaging bug (though it is strange to me that it resulted in an actual core generating crash, rather than a more diagnosable error message), but a bug it still is, and in your supplied delivery.

So, there is no such system, but none would make much sense.

Comment: I'm not discussing the fact whether or not it's a bug, but I'm having troubles with the effort I spent decyphering it: in the 15 years I've been working in this business, I have always known a core-file to mean that a programming mistake has been made (division by zero, null pointer exceptions, ...). Here in this case however I needed to add `catchsegv` commands to the startup parameters in order to have the error message, mentioning that a `stack overflow` was the cause of the issue. I'd expect a system to show such kind of error messages automatically.